# Check if a String with a only Number and space in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I try check a string is number or not.

**number format:**
2222   or  22 22  or 1 2222 or 22323423
(with space before,midlle and after digits)

Is better I use regular expression?
So how can I change it to do that?

```
preg_grep('~^[0-9]$~'
```

or Is there any faster method?

Comment: try this `^[0-9\s]+$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d+( +\d+)*$
```

This will allow 1 or more spaces only in the middle of the number but not at start or end.

Comment: Thanks but I get this error: `Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found`

Comment: @aliraha `/^\d+( +\d+)*$/` better?

Comment: @izier123 Thanks but for example It can not check 33 44

Comment: Can you have spaces before and after numbers also like this `" 33 44          "` ?